# Develop wordpress plugin to create pages with templates

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm a beginner wordpress plugin developer. Our plugin needs to create some specific pages in wordpress. My plugin can create the pages this way in the activation:

```
$page_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status' => 'close',
                'ping_status'    => 'close',
                'post_author'    => 1,
                'post_title'     => ucwords('service network login'),
                'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('service-network-login'))),
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_type'      => 'page',
                )
            );
```

It's ok, I can find my page.
After that I would like to add some php codes to this new page.

I know here can call a php function which generates some html content fo example this way:

```
'post_content'   => my_php_function()
```

But in this case if I change the content of the my_php_function(), then it doesn't affect page content if I refersh the page in browser.

I tried add template file to the page:

```
update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'template.php' );
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I create pages from plugin with dinamic content?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pages are created in the activation, so if you want to update the content, i guess you need to deactivate / activate the plugin

Comment: How this can answer the question?

Comment: I understand from his question that ' my_php_function ' is only triggered in the activation of the plugin, so refreshing the page in the browser won't update the content if he change the code of this function, he needs to deactivate and activate the plugin again